How to avoid AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration when creating a new AWS Elastin Beanstalk application?
Trying to create a AWS Elastic Beanstalk app with Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2023/4.3.8, using pretty much default settings on most configuration settings, like these:

IMDSv1 Deactivated
Environment type Single instance
Availability Zones Any
Fleet composition On-Demand instance
Instance types t3.micro
On-demand base 0
Proxy server nginx

The environment does not want to start though while I am seeing these error events:

Creating Auto Scaling launch configuration failed Reason: Resource
handler returned message: "The Launch Configuration creation
operation is not available in your account. Use launch templates to
create configuration templates for your Auto Scaling groups.
(Service: AutoScaling, Status Code: 400, Request ID:
e4a071d6-34d4-411f-92da-6d19cf888015)" (RequestToken:
a2c39556-2bdd-3403-341a-1679bcb4a272, HandlerErrorCode:
GeneralServiceException)

Stack named 'awseb-e-ex3sx4wzyp-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s)
failed to create: [AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration].

Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Resource AWSEBAutoScalingGroup does not exist for stack
awseb-e-ex3sx4wzyp-stack


The user has admin rights. Any help appreciated :)
EDIT: I did follow an advice and added autoscaling:CreateLaunchConfiguration permission to the user that creates the app. The problem persists.

Maybe this will help. It helped me solve the same problem, only I don't use Doker.
scr

how this help ???please share useful steps to follow

for temporary fix we can use the below way to create the aws beanstalk environment
EnableSpot option set to true. For more information, see Spot instance support and Configuration Auto Scaling group configuration .
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-autoscaling-spot.html

None of the answers here work for me.

Apply the below options in LaunchTemplateData:
MetadataOptions:
  HttpTokens: required  # Enforces IMDSv2 and disables IMDSv1 implicitly
  HttpEndpoint: enabled
  HttpPutResponseHopLimit: 2
  InstanceMetadataTags: enabled


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I am little late to the party, but I faced exact same issue. After tons of research, I found that, easiest way to resolve it it, at the root of our project, we need to

create a folder named .ebextensions, and inside that,
have to create a configuration file autoscaling.config, with the following contents.


    option_settings:
      aws:autoscaling:asg:
        LaunchTemplateName: "your-launch-template"
        LaunchTemplateVersion: "1"


Please note that It is not mandatory create any launch template, either with above name or any other name. Beanstalk will try to look for the template with that name, and if it does not find it, it will create a new one with default settings, will create default LoadBalancer and default Auto Scaling group, if not configured during environment creation. I tried this small step on my own as well, and it works fine, launches environment without any above errors.
I found this solution only in one of the forums online and I can't find the exact link now, don't know why, and even official docs of AWS did not mention anywhere to do this, they should add it soon as this is the most simplest solution for this problem I have encountered so far.
Try it and let me know if it worked or not.

Did you tested this proposal?

Yes @ivanleoncz, I did actually. And it worked perfectly.

I had the same issue and what worked for me after trying for days was to:
DisableIMDSv1: true
Setting RootVolumeType to: gp3
I hope that helps

how to set RootVolumeType to: gp3 wheere ?? any step by step guide ??
